# Retrieve Profile information for an asp.net membership user account

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership

I want to pass an asp.net membership user name to a subroutine and retrieve the profile property named **FullName** for that user, how can i achive this in vb.net?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this is off the top of my head and my vb.net is rusty so treat it like psuedo code that *may* run as-is

```
Public Function GetProfileFullName(username as String) as String
   Dim profile as ProfileBase = ProfileBase.Create(username);
   Return profile.GetPropertyValue("FullName") as String;
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to extend the ASP.NET Membership API for this.

follow this article to see how: http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0703071